# error in make-messages.py

Tags: python, django

I run this command:

```
make-messages.py -l fa
```

but it has this error:
'make-messages.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I run it in my project root,app roo and django root,but all of them cause this error
what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's obsolete. You should replace invoking `make-messages.py` with `django-admin.py makemessages`.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command in project root

```
python manage.py makemessages -l fa
```